# How to solve nonlinear differential equation involving exponential functions

Tags: laplace-transform, differential, nonlinear-dynamics

I have a differential equation of the form below:

$$k_1\frac{df(t)}{dt} + (k_2 + k_3e^{k_4 f(t)})f(t) = x(t)$$

I want to find the solution of $f(t)$ as a function of $x(t)$. In other words, I want to find the dynamic response of $f(t)$ to $x(t)$.

First, I tried to use Laplace transforms to find something that looks like a transfer function, and then simply convert it back into time domain. However, I notice that the exponent term makes it a bit complicated. So I decided to first simplify the equation using some substitution for the exponential term. I know that 
$$\frac{de^{f(t)}}{dt} = e^{f(t)} \frac{df}{dt}$$

But I can't seem to be able to apply this information. Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a nonlinear equation, there is no simple "dynamic response": it is unlikely that you can get anything like a closed form for the dependence of the solution on $x(t)$. In this case I don't even think there's a closed form for the solution in the case $x(t)=t$. Laplace transforms are unlikely to be helpful for nonlinear differential equations.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Are there any software tools I can use for this?

Comment: Maple is one of the best in terms of solving differential equations in closed form, but it doesn't find anything in the case I mentioned.